# Scene2d Positioning Components on Stack

Tags: libgdx

This is current state: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRYXL.png)

But there are 2 more things I want to do:

1. moving the stack to the top left of the screen
2. In the image, I divided the parchment into two parts, I want to put 2 labels on the upper part and 2-3 text buttons on the lower part.

*related codes*:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.center();
table.setFillParent(true);

Stack stack = new Stack();

titleLabel.setFontScale(0.5f);
label1.setFontScale(0.5f);
textButton.getLabel().setFontScale(0.5f);
textButton2.getLabel().setFontScale(0.5f);

parchment.setScaling(Scaling.fill);
stack.add(parchment);

Table overlay = new Table();
overlay.add(titleLabel).expand();
overlay.row();
overlay.add(label1).expand();
overlay.row();
overlay.add(textButton).expand();
overlay.row();
overlay.add(textButton2).expand();

stack.add(overlay);

table.add(stack).top().left();

stage.addActor(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do in situations like this is to set debug on any tables you have - you will then be able to see the boundary lines showing how big the table is and how big the cells in the tables are. Simply do this:

```
table.setDebug(true);
```

> 1. moving the stack to the top left of the screen

With debug set, I can see that your stack isn't filling the whole table or the whole screen. Stacks only grow to fit their contents, they will not fill the their container automatically, so to fill the screen add "expand()" to the Stack's cell in the Table like this:

```
table.add(stack).expand().top().left();
```

> 2. In the image, I divided the parchment into two parts, I want to put 2 labels on the upper part and 2-3 text buttons on the lower part.

You can do this in one of two ways. You could make a table for each group which would be a good approach if there are lots of items in each group. Or if there are only a few items you can add "expand()" to force the items in the middle to push the other items up/down, like this:

```
        Table table = new Table();
//        table.setDebug(true);
        table.setFillParent(true);

        Stack stack = new Stack();

        titleLabel.setFontScale(0.5f);
        label1.setFontScale(0.5f);
        textButton.getLabel().setFontScale(0.5f);
        textButton2.getLabel().setFontScale(0.5f);

        parchment.setScaling(Scaling.fill);
        stack.add(parchment);

        Table overlay = new Table();
//        overlay.setDebug(true);
        overlay.add(titleLabel).top();
        overlay.row();
        overlay.add(label1).expand().top();
        overlay.row();
        overlay.add(textButton).expand().bottom();
        overlay.row();
        overlay.add(textButton2).bottom();

        stack.add(overlay);

        table.add(stack).expand().top().left();

        stage.addActor(table);
```